# Place an iframe in a blog and make it fit correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, blogger

Ok, so I have made a blog for my wife who is in real estate. I am familiar with html and css, but I seem to have hit a wall. I have been researching it for a little now and would like some direction.
I removed the side bars using css, but somehow I missed something and cant figure out how to expand the center post section to make it the full width. Thats one, the second issue is getting the iframe to fit right which probably ties into the first one.
so the site is: http://tamapabayrealestate.blogspot.com/p/blog-page_79.html
and the code i used to get it there is:

```
<style>
#sidebar-wrapper, #midsidebar-wrapper, #main-column-right-sections, #sidebar-left-1, 
#sidebar-right-1, #main-column-left-sections,.gapad2, 
 .blog-pager,.fauxcolumn-left-outer, .fauxcolumn-inner, 
 .post-header-line-1, .post-footer { display:none !important;} 
#post-body-456672082127024910 { width:98%!important;} 
 .body .content-inner { width:98%!important; }
</style>
<iframe src="http://mfr.mlsmatrix.com/Matrix/Public/AWP/gloriaalfonso/?L=1&ap=SCH" 
      style="border:0px #000000 none;" 
       name="My iFrame" 
  scrolling="yes" 
frameborder="1" 
marginheight="px" 
marginwidth="0px" 
     height="850px" 
     width="800px"></iframe>`
```

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem seems to be that ".main-inner .columns" has padding. Try:

```
.main-inner .columns {padding:0;}
```

Comment: that seemed to have fixed it, but how do I get the content of the iframe to fit a little better?

Comment: I'm afraid there is not much you can do, at least from your page. For security reasons, you are not able to modify with code in your page an iframe's content. In the iframe page, ".portalCentered" is set to a min-width of 1000px, so if you have access to it, that's what you'd have to change.

Comment: I get it, thanks a ton!! Should've just asked in the first place instead of trying to remember what I once knew from like 5 yrs ago! lol

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be that you've essentially restricted the maximum width of blog content with this `.body .content-inner { width:98%!important; }` but then you're defining exact widths for your iFrame (width = 800px). The result is your iFrame is getting cut off because it it's wider than the body of the blog.

It seems likely that you'll run into other issues but: try changing the iFrame's width to 100% (vs. 850px) and see if that resolves part of the issue. If that doesn't work, also add `position: relative;` following `border:0px #000000 none;` separated by a space, but still in the double quotes.

If it does what I think it will, it will fix the width issue, but then wind up looking distorted (too tall for how wide it has suddenly become). You could then change the height to 90vw (or whatever number give you the proper aspect ratio! 90 may not be the correct number...my math is failing me, so you could just experiment with it).

There's a lot of context missing, so honestly this could complicate rather than fix. Just keep careful track of what you do (or better: a backup file!) and undo all the changes I suggested if things get out of hand :)

Comment: Thanks, combined with @cooperista I was able to make it work, just curious is there a way to make the iframe content fit better? I also noticed that there is no scrolling in iframe anymore, when did html stop that one?